# Mean of 3D array with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I’m new to python/numpy prorammation.
I have a 3-dimensional array representing an image (x and y axis) and each point of the image is associated with a pixel with its rgb values:
So for example:
a = np.array([[[0, 2, 2], [1, 3, 2]], [[1, 4, 5], [6, 5, 3]]])
I'd like to compute the mean of the R, G, and B color channels over the image.
For exemple (0+1+1+6)/4, (2+3+4+5)/4, (2+2+5+3)/4.
And i have to use the function numpy.mean.
I’ve tested several things by slicing but I feel it’s not the right thing to do: (patch == image)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2HKx.png)
thx for your help !

Comment: `a.mean((0, 1))`?

Comment: Thx for ur answer, its seems to work but i think i have to use something like : numpy.mean(my_array, 0/1)

Comment: `np.mean` has a dedicated argument `axis`: e.g. `np.mean(a, axis=0)`

Comment: When I do that, I get a 2-dimensional table and I don’t see why.

Comment: there is an error with the brackets in the question, so can you clarify the array properly please...

Comment: oops srry about that

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider this array `rgb`

```
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0]]])
```

Then mean values for each channel we can get it by

```
import numpy as np

rgb = np.array([[[1,1,1],[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[1,2,3],[0,0,0],[1,0,0]]])
print(rgb.shape)

rgb_mean = np.mean(np.mean(rgb, axis=1), axis=0)
print(rgb_mean)
rgb_mean = rgb_mean.astype(np.uint8)
print(rgb_mean.shape)
print(rgb_mean)
```

output

```
(2, 3, 3)
```

```
array([1.33333333, 1.66666667, 2.16666667])
```

```
(3,)
```

```
array([1, 1, 2], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: RGB colors has to be of data type uint8, so I added the line that will convert the floating values into uint8

Comment: `np.mean(rgb, axis=1)` will give column wise mean for each of the image rows ```array([[2.        , 2.66666667, 3.33333333],
       [0.66666667, 0.66666667, 1.        ]])``` and then we need to again perform a column wise mean calculation (axis=0 of array with shape (2,3))

Comment: I don't really understand the line rgb_mean = np.mean(np.mean(rgb, axis=1), axis=0). Why do u operate on line for the inside mean call ? Thx a lot for u previous answer !